# AngularJS - How to access a binding value within ng-switch

Tags: angularjs

Within a ng-repeat I have a ng-switch conditional. I want the value of the ng-switch argument to be a binding. However the curly-bracket binding doesn't seem to be converted into the expected generated value. I'm aware that ng-switch creates a new scope, and that is surely causing the problem. I know about a ['dot' work-around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15593299/angularjs-ng-switch-does-not-bind-ng-model) but as the values here are coming from a service via a controller query, I can't figure out how to implement it in this situation.

**html**

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in users">
    <td ng-switch on="editState"><p ng-switch-when="noEdit">{{user.username}}</p><input type="text" value="{{user.username}}" ng-switch-when="{{user.username}}"></td>
</tr>
```

**controller.js**

```
$scope.users = Users.query();
```

-edit-

this is the function that triggers the switch

```
$scope.editUser = function(usernameEdit) {
    $scope.editState = usernameEdit;
};
```

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do here: `ng-switch-when="{{user.username}}"`?  Can you instead use ng-switch-default?

Comment: This table row is to be repeated for each user. When I press the 'edit' link next to each user i want the switch conditional to match just that username and so hide the paragraph and show the text input. If I used switch default wouldn't all the users in the list switch?

Comment: I've also added the function that triggers the switch argument

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A single `$scope.editState` won't work if you want to be able to edit multiple users at the same time.  I suggest putting an `edit` property on each `user`, and use that property to control the ng-switch:

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in users">
   <td ng-switch on="user.edit"> 
      <span ng-switch-when="true">
         <input  type="text" value="{{user.username}}">
         <a href="" ng-click="user.edit=false">done</a>
      </span>
      <p ng-switch-default>
         <a href="" ng-click="user.edit=true">edit</a> {{user.username}}
      </p>
   </td>
</tr>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/MW7cq/)

Comment: Brilliant thanks for making it so clear, it seems I didn't really understand ng-switch from the angular docs