# Angularjs v1 Kendo UI DOM element access with $scope when there is a ng-switch-when

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui

With Kendo UI component in Angularjs, for example:

```
<input kendo-date-picker="myDatePicker"
       ng-model="dateString"
       k-ng-model="dateObject"
       style="width: 100%;" />
```

I am able to access the date picker in javascript with the variable `$scope.myDatePicker`

Now, the problem is, this date-picker comes with a wrapper with the tag `ng-switch-when`.

```
<div ng-switch="userSelection.code">
   <div ng-switch-when="JUST_DEMO">
      <input kendo-date-picker="myDatePicker"
         ng-model="dateString"
         k-ng-model="dateObject"
         style="width: 100%;" />
   </div>
</div>
```

With this, in the javascript, the variable `$scope.myDatePicker` becomes '`undefined`', even though after the flag `JUST_DEMO` is turned on subsequently.

So my question is, how to fix this? I need to access `$scope.myDatePicker` in javascript to manually open the datepicker in the code.

**P.S.:**

<s>I think I found a working approach: using `$compile` in the `databound` event.</s>

Answer (score 1):

i don't see any code for `ng-switch` , not sure if it's there in your tag :

```
<div ng-switch="myVar">
```

`ng-switch` is evaluated against `myVar` variable in abve code snippet.

I suggest you use ng-switch as follows :

declare a scope variable with some sort of flag to base your `ng-switch` on

```
$scope.datePickerParent = {};// some object
datePickerParent .JUST_DEMO = true/false;
datePickerParent.myDatePicker = ''; //assign some value
<td ng-switch on="datePickerParent.showNgSwitch"> 

    <div ng-switch-when="datePickerParent.JUST_DEMO">
   <input kendo-date-picker="datePickerParent.myDatePicker"
       ng-model="dateString"
       k-ng-model="dateObject"
       style="width: 100%;" />
   </div>
   </td>
```

Also have a look at this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15905562/1531476)

Also try to use `$parent` to access scope variable, `ng-switch` creates it's own scope

Comment: Sorry, my mistake that overlooks the ng-switch (just edited). But i think the problem is, at first, since the ng-switch-when condition isn't fulfilled, so the html isn't created on loaded. And for some reason, although it is fulfilled afterwards, the $scope variable is still undefined....

Comment: what i meant to convey in my response is may be ng-switch-when can't directly access JUST_DEMO IMHO , it has to be via ng-switch variable i.e. userSelection.JUST_DEMO as referred in linked post

Comment: hm...understand your words now. But I am afraid this may not be the cause. As I do see the kendo-date-picker being rendered on the page. Just that, I couldn't access it with the $scope variable...

Comment: try to use `$parent` to access scope variable, `ng-switch` creates it's own scope

Comment: did you find a solution ?

Comment: nope. But thanks for your words "ng-switch creates its's own scope". I am looking from this direction...

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```
<div ng-switch="userSelection.code">
   <div ng-switch-when="JUST_DEMO">
      <input kendo-date-picker="myKendo.myDatePicker"
         ng-model="dateString"
         k-ng-model="dateObject"
         style="width: 100%;" />
   </div>
</div>
```

instead of using the normal "`myDatePicker`" variable, wrap it in another object, such as `myKendo`.

So, in javascript, this can be accessed with `$scope.myKendo.myDatePicker.`