# How to use databinding in two views with same controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angularjs-ng-include

Imagine a simple variable string in a controller `MyCtrl`:

```
$scope.simpleString = 'hi i am your simple string!';
```

which is the the Angular *model* of a simple text `input`:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="simpleString">
```

This input now is used in two different views *part1* and *part2*:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div ng-include="'part1'"></div>
    <div ng-include="'part2'"></div>
</div>
```

Using two different views seems to break my databinding although it is supposed to be in the `MyCtrl` *scope*.

Info: I also tried to use `ui-view` but it boils down to the very same thing.

Comment: what do you mean by breaks the databinding?

Comment: changing the `input` *model* in one view does not update the other view

Comment: Your problem is most probably the top level binding and prototypical inheritance, because `ng-include` creates a new scope. Do `$scope.mydata.simpleString = '...'` and `<input type="text" ng-model="mydata.simpleString">`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJS - losing scope when using ng-include](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11412410/angularjs-losing-scope-when-using-ng-include)

Answer (score 1):

you need to set $scope.simpleString to be an object like this:

```
$scope.data = {
  simpleString: 'John'
}
```

that'll prevent the variables from shadowing one another.
I wrote an answer relating this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26649708/2460773)