# ng-model in checkbox seems one way

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a checkbox that is updated from the model, but then the model is not updated clicking the checkbox.

Within a form I have:

```
<input type="checkbox"  ng-model="acceptEula"> I have read the EULA and I agree
<button type="submit" ng-click="pay()" translate>Proceed to Pay</button>
{{acceptEula}}
```

Clicking the checkbox, I can see how {{acceptEula}} shows true or false, it works.

When I click the button, I put a breakdown in pay() function.  $scope.acceptEula is always false.  What could be the problem?

Comment: How confident are you that there's no scoping issues going on? I'd make sure that you declare `$scope.acceptEula = false` in your controller so that inheritance works properly. Even better would be `$scope.formData.acceptEula = false`.

Comment: Yes, in the controller I have  $scope.acceptEula = false. In fact, if I change it to  $scope.acceptEula = true; then the checkbox is checked and  $scope.acceptEula is true in the debugger. The thing is that I have the same problem, I check off the control, but then the debugger continues giving me true.

Comment: @DabielKabuto please see here http://jsbin.com/wonuyuzege/1/edit seems to working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, the question was not detailed in order to simplify the problem. In reality, I used "ng-switch" in the form.
Finally I have found the problem: "This is a scope inheritance problem due to ng-switch creating it's own scope.". It is well explained at [angularjs - ng-switch does not bind ng-model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15593299/angularjs-ng-switch-does-not-bind-ng-model)

The solution is to use dot in the model, for example $scope.form.acceptEula