# Angular JS - template of a directive ng -model does not work within ng -switch

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

To become more dynamic my directive decided to include the category field that makes the selection of the type of template to be displayed. As it is only a select thought of using the switch - ng instead of several html files. (google translate)

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/fnCJj15XJN1kQvKq1OtZ?p=preview

**index.html**

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<sg-combo 
  selected-item="selectedItem" categoria="filtro">
</sg-combo>

{{selectedItem}}
```

**script.js**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.selectedItem = {value: null};
  $scope.$watch('selectedItem',function(item){
  if (item != null){
    alert(item.nome); // does not display when updating
  }
 })
});

app.directive('sgCombo', function(){
function link(scope, elem, attrs){    
        scope.dados = [
            {'codigo':1, 'nome':'teste1'},
            {'codigo':2, 'nome':'teste2'},
            {'codigo':3, 'nome':'teste3'}
        ];
}

return {
        restrict: 'E',          
    scope: {            
        selectedItem: '=',            
        categoria: '@'            
    },
    link: link,
    templateUrl:"sg-combo.html"
 }
})
```

**sg-combo.html**

```
<div ng-switch="categoria">
 <div ng-switch-when="filtro" class="col-sm-4 control-label">
   <div class="col-sm-4 control-label">
     <label>{{label}}</label>
     <select ng-model="selectedItem.value" ng-options="item.nome for item in dados" class="form-control"></select>
   </div>
 </div>
 <div ng-switch-when="anexo" class="col-sm-4 control-label">
  <div class="col-sm-4 control-label">
    <label>{{label}}</label>
    <select ng-model="selectedItem.value" ng-options="item.nome for item in dados" class="form-control"></select>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: replied in **stackoverflow portugueses** https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/105410/angular-js-template-de-uma-directiva-com-ng-model-n%C3%A3o-funciona-dentro-de-ng-sw/106260#106260

Answer (score 0):

Try to make 'selectedItem' a part of an object. 
For instance:

In controller:
$scope.options = {'selectedItem': someItem};

In template: 
ng-model="options.selectedItem"

Comment: I see you edited the code, doing excatly what I suggested here. Did it work? If so, an upvote would be nice :)

Answer (score 0):

[ng-switch adds a scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15593299/angularjs-ng-switch-does-not-bind-ng-model) and you [should use '.' in ng-model](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes).

Comment: It is bad idea to change original code in question, so my answer may confuse somebody. Please check [original version](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34533654/revisions)